# haskell: convert one member of a list of lists from char to int

Tags: list, haskell, char, int

Suppose I have a list like this one:

```
list= [["a","123","b"],["h","435","t"],["w","234","j"]]
```

What I need is to convert each second member of that list of lists into an `Integer` because it will serve as a size indicator after that so I can sort my list by size.

I've came up with a function for conversion:

```
charToInt c = ord (chr c)
```

but I dont know how to convert each second member of the list.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?  The uniformity of the inner lists makes it look like they are really some kind of structure in disguise.  The fact that you want to sort by the length of the second element makes this seem even more likely.  So I wonder if you are thinking of these lists as a kind of dynamically typed structure?

Comment: Hey Paul, what i'm trying to achiev is a progam that will give me all meta data of some files in a list of lists, something lihe this:
`list=[["music_A","size_A","artist_A",...],["music_B","size_B","artist_B",...]...]`
all meta data comes in `String` and as after i want to give the user the oportunity to sort all the data by size i need to convert the size to an `Int`

Comment: As I suspected, you are trying to use a list as a data structure.  This is a bad idea.  You need to create a data structure to hold your data using native types (like Integer for the size), and then define a function such as mkMetaData :: [String] -> MetaData. then you can have a list of that data type and sort it however you like.

Comment: I see your point, i'll give it a try mate, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To expand on what Paul Johnson said, you need to define a datatype for the data you're trying to hold.

```
data MusicFile = MusicFile {music :: String,
                            size :: Integer,
                            artist :: String}
    deriving Show

musicFileFromStrings :: [String] -> MusicFile
musicFileFromStrings [sMusic, sSize, sArtist]
   = MusicFile sMusic (read sSize) sArtist
```

Then if you have

```
list = [["a","123","b"],["h","435","t"],["w","234","j"]]
```

you can say

```
anotherList = map musicFileFromStrings list
```

and then

```
map music anotherList   -- ["a", "h", "w"]
map artist anotherList  -- ["b", "t", "j"]
```

(EDIT)

If you want to sort the list by a particular field you can use "sortBy" and "[comparing](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Ord.html)".

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

sizeOrderList = sortBy (comparing size) anotherList
```

The "comparing" function turns a function on a value (in this case "size") into a comparison function between two values.  The only requirement is that the output of "size" (in this case) be a type that is an instance of "Ord".

If you want descending order than use

```
sizeOrderList = sortBy (comparing (flip size)) anotherList
```

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for the help. I've follow what you said but when i try to run `anotherList` i get this error:
`No instance for (Show MusicFile)
      arising from a use of `print'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Show MusicFile)
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it`

Comment: ok i got it to work just adding `deriving Show` but now i have the same problem i had at the bigining, instead of having  this

`[["ad",23,"fd"],["g",54,"gs"],["yt",67,"fh"]]`,
i have this:
`[MusicFile {music = "ad", size = 23, artist = "fd"},MusicFile {music = "g", size = 54, artist = "gs"},MusicFile {music = "yt", size = 67, artist = "fh"}]`

Comment: See my edits. Do you need a tutorial on how to use records in Haskell?

Comment: I think u didnt understand me, you just created two lists with all the music and all the artists, but i don't want to have it that way, i want all meta data from one file toghether, because later i will have to transform that info to pdf so the user will see all the information from each file on the screen.

Comment: Mate, i've seen your post about Daniel's answer: `map (\(x:y:xs) -> S x : I (read y) : map S xs) list` and it's working and its almost perfect, the only thing wrong is this: `[[S "ad",I 23,S "fd"],[S "g",I 54,S "gs"],[S "yt",I 67,S "fh"]]` the result came out with the S and I of each type. Any idea of how to get rid of them?
Sorry to bother and thanks a lot for your help

Comment: So now you need to define a prettyprint function that generates the text for each record.  You can use "sortBy" and "comparing" to shuffle the list into whatever order you want.  E.g. "sortBy (comparing sSize) listOfMusic" will do what you want.

Comment: i already have the prettyprinting function running, only thing left to do is just clean the results of that map as said before: `[[S "ad",I 23,S "fd"],[S "g",I 54,S "gs"],[S "yt",I 67,S "fh"]]`, if i take those S and I its done

Comment: @seph I know you don't actually want a list of all the artists. You seemed not to know how to extract data from a record.

Comment: If you mean the meta data from the records i'm using, i have to extract them with exiftool, it's a demand by the teacher. and yes mate, i know that i'm lvl 1 haskell user but i'm trying, and i gotta start from the bottom, so sorry for my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot convert the second element of the inner lists to an `Integer` without changing the type from a list to something like a tuple. The reason is that lists are homogeneous in Haskell, so you need a tuple to represent mixed types.

Converting a `String` into an `Integer` is done like this:

```
read "123" :: Integer
```

You need to add the type directly since the type of `read` is `Read a => String -> a`, meaning that it'll return something of a type that can be "read". Luckily, `Integer` is a member of that type class, so we can convert `String` into `Integer`.

Now it's just a simple matter of converting the second element of each inner list:

```
convert :: [[String]] -> [(String, Integer, String)]
convert lists = map (\[a, b, c] -> (a, read b, c)) lists
```

Comment: That's a very nice solution mate, but i was in need of keeping the same structure, there's no way to that u say?

Comment: Right, there's no way. Except if you transform it to lists of another type, say `data D = S String | I Integer`, then `map ((x:y:xs) -> S x : I (read y) : map S xs) list` gives you a `[[D]]` which you can then treat as you desired.

Comment: I like this way more: convert = map (\[a,b,c] -> (a, (read b), c))

Comment: Daniel i've tried as u said, to transform the type of the list but when i run this code:
`map ((x:y:xs) -> S x : I (read y) : map S xs) [["sd","45","b"],["j","54","g"],["a","33","d"]]`
i get this error 
`Pattern syntax in expression context:
        (x : y : xs) -> S x : I (read y) : map S xs`

but if this works, it's perfect, totally what i need

Comment: Ondra, i've tried your way and i got this 

`Pattern syntax in expression context: [a, b, c] -> (a, (read b), c)`

Comment: Should be `map (\(x:y:xs) -> S x : I (read y) : map S xs) list` or `convert = map (\[a,b,c] -> (a, (read b), c))`.